# Laravel, phpunit test completed but it says it's risky?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I just created a simple test like this:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class ResponseTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testHomePage()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();
        $response = $this->actingAs($user)
                                    ->get('/');
        $response->assertSuccessful();
        $user->forceDelete();
    }
}
```

I run phpunit and I get:

```
PHPUnit 6.3.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 7.1.9-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
Configuration: /home/vagrant/laravel/phpunit.xml

R                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 1.87 seconds, Memory: 14.00MB

There was 1 risky test:

1) Tests\Unit\ResponseTest::testHomePage
Test code or tested code did not (only) close its own output buffers

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Risky: 1.
```

Now can anyone explain to me how to avoid this risky error? here's my phpunit.xml as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    backupGlobals="false"
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>

        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

I can't see anything wrong with my code neither I do know why it keeps saying that the best is risky. This is my first time doing the tests so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you get this error if you don't `forceDelete` at the end?

Comment: yes, I tried it and still get it

Comment: Did you set any flags in the command line? Or just ran `phpunit`? In addition to any flags you may have set, give it the `-v` flag to get verbose output

Comment: that is the verbose output @ishegg

Comment: Right, missed the bit about the output buffers, sorry. [See here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/src/Framework/TestCase.php#L2170), might help you solve it. Any of those methods open a buffer? Further, what is that `factory()` function? I'm unfamiliar with it.

Comment: What happens if you comment out everything else and just assert true? `$this->assertTrue(true);`

Comment: @ishegg that method is to generate a random user data and insert to the table. Something like dummy data